# How to toggle between the windows of native desktop and windows within vnc viewer?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I am using Windows 10 Operating System, and i have installed VNC Viewer 6.7 on top of it.

And using VNC Viewer, i will be connecting to a remote server running some *nix flavor of OS. So again there will be multiple windows opened on the remote server. Hence i could see multiple windows inside VNC Viewer itself. Let us call these windows as **v1, v2, v3, v4**.

And in my host OS (win 10), there will be multiple applications running. Hence there will be multiple windows within Windows 10 itself. Let us call these windows as **W1, W2, W3, W4(VNC Viewer)**; where W4, is the VNC Viewer's window

If i want to navigate between *W1 and W2* or *W2 and W3*, so issues i could use the keyboard shortcut **ALT+TAB** (the default key combination).

However, if i enter/select into W4, (VNC Viewer window), then **ALT+TAB** would start navigate between *v1 and v2* or *v2 and v3* or *v3 and v4*.

So, we are able to navigate between W* to v* windows (ie from host OS windows to remote OS windows through VNC Viewer). 
**However, we are not able to navigate the other way round, ie from v* to W* (from windows from remote OS to host OS) - without intervention of mouse**

So could anyone help me out to get rid of this problem?
I want to navigate between windows v* to W* using keyboard shortcut. Say, CTRL+ALT or some hot-key combination should bring the control out of VNC Viewer back to the host OS.

Comment: Answered on [so] - [Key mappings in RealVNC client](//stackoverflow.com/q/4264278)

Comment: It doesn't have a right answer what I'm looking for, David. It just gives the answer for how to navigate between v*to W* but no way to navigate between v* to v*.

Comment: See the [so] link I posted ...